# Parse json error

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the following JSON using the javascript eval() function.

```
`[{"pk": 1, "model": "relayapp.team", "fields": {"company": 1, "signup": true, "name": "Cool"}}]` 

    function setupTable(data)
    {
        var info = eval("(" + data + ")");
        var string = "";
        for(item in info.fields) 
        {
            record = info.fields[item];
            string = string + "<tr><td>" + record.name + "</td><td> </td><td> " + record.signup + "</td><td></td><td> </td></tr>";

        }
        document.getElementById("team_table_body").innerHTML = string;
    }`
```

It comes up with this error in the console debugger.

```
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier           teamList.html:54
                       setupTable                      teamList.html:54
                       (anonymous function)            teamList.html:48
                       l                               jquery.min.js:2
                       c.fireWith                      jquery.min.js:2
                       T                               jquery.min.js:2
                       r                               jquery.min.js:2`
```

Comment: As an aside, you should probably be using `JSON.parse` (with a shim for older browsers) instead of `eval`

Comment: You don't need the tildes (`) in your code - the four spaces at the start of each line do that for you. As it is, I think those would be syntax errors in JS, so they might be confusing...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HcTfm/)

**JS**

```
function setupTable(data)
{
    var info = eval("(" + data + ")");
    var string = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
        record = info[i];
        string = string + "<tr><td>" + record.fields.name + "</td><td> </td><td> " + record.fields.signup + "</td><td></td><td> </td></tr>";

    }
    document.getElementById("team_table_body").innerHTML = string;
}


setupTable('[{"pk": 1, "model": "relayapp.team", "fields": {"company": 1, "signup": true, "name": "Cool"}}]');
```

**HTML**

```
<table id='team_table_body'></table>
```